# Contents and format of URI when uploading or downloading file

Tags: java, upload, uri

I have an application which is an API on a server (say 192.168.0.2), to which files (of any format) can be uploaded or from which they can be downloaded.

If an application on another machine on the network (say 192.196.0.3) wants to upload a file to the API, it passes the information in a JSON Object e.g. { "FILE_LOCATION":"file:/192.168.0.3/c:/testDocs/testFile.docx" }

The code in the api goes roughly:

```
private static void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String errorMessage = "";
    try
    {
        String src = request.getParameter ("src");
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse (src);
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        String fileLocation = (String) jsonObj.get ("FILE_LOCATION");
        URI uri = new URI (fileLocation);
        URL url = uri.toURL ();    // get URL from your uri object
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection ();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream ();

        System.out.println ("InputStream = " + is);
        if (is != null)
        {
            // create output file, output stream etc
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorMessage = e.getMessage ();
        System.out.println (e.getClass().getName () + " : " + errorMessage);
    }

    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter ();
    pw.append (errorMessage);
}
```

The system log invariably shows something like:
"java.io.FileNotFoundException : 192.168.0.3/c:/testDocs/testFile.docx (No such file or directory)"

What am I doing wrong? I am convinced that the fault lies in the way I have constructed the String which will be used to create the URI.

Answer (score 0):

That does not look like a valid `file:` URL. On Windows you could try to check if a file is accessible from a remote server if `dir` works in `CMD.EXE`. For example, try UNC pathname:

```
dir \\IP_OR_HOSTNAME\NAMEOFSHARE\path\etc\filename.xyz
```

**If** that works - and that rather depends on whether the remote server is serving that filesystem as `NAMEOFSHARE` - then the equivalent `file:` encoding of above would be:

```
String u = new File("\\\\IP_OR_HOSTNAME\\NAMEOFSHARE\\path\\etc\\filename.xyz").toURL().toString();
==> "file://IP_OR_HOSTNAME/NAMEOFSHARE/path/etc/filename.xyz"
```

Comment: Thanks. What I am trying to send is; "file://[IP address]/[listening port number]/[drive:]/[path]/filename. Is this even valid?

Comment: That does not look like format for valid file protocol to a Windows host (also I don't think Windows machines expose their `drive:` letters to other servers).